# CSS line after text effect on multiline texts

Tags: css

I am trying to acheive the red title effect shown on the image:

[image]

I've tried doing it with a `linear-gradient` background but I cannot do it since the page has a background, as I would need to apply another background to the text to get this effect and it would be obvious since the text background would not match the page background. I've also tried doing it with `box-decoration-break` to no success.

Since it was asked on the comments I am providing a code example. This is the most similar effect I could acheive: [codepen.io/jorditarrida/pen/eYNQGqa](https://codepen.io/jorditarrida/pen/eYNQGqa). It isn't really the desired effect since the title text does have a background which occludes the jigsaw background behind it. I probably would need a radically different approach.

How can I acheive it? Ideally in pure CSS and it should work on IE11. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the red text is a single element or they are two elements?

Comment: Show us your code please (sisplau)

Comment: @vals I don't really have a working code for this. This is the most similar effect I could acheive: https://codepen.io/jorditarrida/pen/eYNQGqa. It isn't really the desired effect since the title text does have a background which occludes the jigsaw background behind it. I probably would need a radically different approach.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan It really doesn't matter. Ideally a single element (you can forget about the line break inside the title). If a wrapping element is needed for the effect, this could be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be using a pseudo element could be a solution.

In this case, your span should be a single line (But you said in comments this was not an issue)

```css
.base {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<span>Some Text</span>
</div>
```

As asked, there is a possibility to set this effect on a multiline span.

But it's using blending, so it won't work on IE

```css
.base {
  height: 150px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, lightblue 0px, lightyellow 40px);
  width: 430px;
}


.bkg {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, red 0px, red 5px, white 5px, white 34px);
  background-position: center 15px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

span {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="bkg">
<span>Some Text that is really long and spans several lines</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vals, I probably wasn't clear enough on the comments. The effect should be able to span between multiple lines, and I cannot count that each line of text can be inside its own element. What I meant is that I didn't matter if an extra wrapping element (for all the text) was added.

Comment: I am upvoting you anyway since this is the approach I will use if I cannot find a more suitable solution.

Comment: Added another solution, that will work for multiline spans, but not on old browsers

Comment: Thanks you very much @vals (moltes gràcies)! It now does what the designer expected. I updated my original codepen to reflect it: https://codepen.io/jorditarrida/pen/eYNQGqa. I will check what we can do for older browsers.

Comment: Gracies i cuidat